# Problem using DOMPDF. I've already done everything recommended

Tags: dompdf

I'm getting the error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "dompdf\dompdf" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\portalssmg\z9400b_pdf.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main}

And I don't understand why.

I use VENDOR for PHPMAILER

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
//Load Composer's autoloader
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
//configurações básicas de endereço e protoloco 
$mail = new PHPMailer; //faz a instância do objeto PHPMailer
```

And it works fine.

I use VENDOR for EXCEL

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
```

And it works fine.

I use it for DOMPDF and it doesn't work.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use dompdf\dompdf;
//require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';   
$dompdf = new dompdf();
```

And it doesn't work. I've done everything and I can't.
Can anyone help?

The DOMPDF doesn't work and I'm already desperate.